# Search Multiple Columns In Model Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

I now have a simple search form that will search one column in my model and return results as expected, however I would like to build upon this by being able to search upon 4 columns within the same model, using 4 text_field/Select_tags.

I have looked at Gems that provide this like solr for example but my thinking is that it seems a bit overkill for what i want to achieve, especially on such a small app

the app is simple, you can upload recipes, add recipes to favourites and search recipes.

So far it looks like this

Controller

```
 def search
 @countrysearch = Recipe.where(:country_of_origin => params[:search]).all
 end
```

Search Form

```
 <%= form_tag({:controller => 'search', :action => 'search'}, {:method => 'get'})  do |s| %>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
 <% end %>
```

Output (View)

```
  <% @countrysearch.each do |r| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= r.dish_name %></td>
   <td><%= r.country_of_origin %></td>
   <td><%= r.difficulty %></td>
   <td><%= r.preperation_time %></td>
   <td><%= ingredient_names(r.ingredients) %></td>
   <td><%= preperation_steps(r.preperations) %></td>
 </tr>
```

I would like my search form to mirror my "Create New recipe Form" with select tags

```
  <%= f.label :dish_name, "Dish Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :dish_name, :placeholder => "Enter Dish Name" %>

  <%= f.label :country_of_origin, "Country Of Origin" %>
  <%= f.select :country_of_origin,  [['Wales'],['Scotland'],['England']], {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>

  <%= f.label :difficulty, "Difficulty Level" %>
  <%= f.select :difficulty, [['Beginner'],['Intermediate'],['Expert']], {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>


  <%= f.select :preperation_time, [['15..30'],['30..60'],['60..120']], {:include_blank => 'Please Select'} %>


 <% end %>
```

Just some pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using all the parameters you have passed to controller:

```
def search
 @countrysearch = Recipe.where({:dish_name => params[:search][:dish_name], :country_of_origin => params[:search][:country_of_origin], :difficulty => params[:search][:difficulty], :preperation_time => params[:search][:preperation_time]}).all
end
```

This should work for you. There are other alternatives, but if you want a simple one, this may fit you.

**Edit:**

If you don't have other things in your search for, you can do something like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'search', :action => 'search'}, {:method => 'get'})  do |s| %>
 <%= text_field_tag :dish_name, params[:dish_name] %>
 <%= select_tag "country_of_origin", options_from_collection_for_select(@recipes, "country_of_origin", "country_of_origin_name")
 <%= select_tag "difficulty ", options_from_collection_for_select(@recipe, "difficulty ", "difficulty ")
 <%= select_tag "preperation_time", options_from_collection_for_select(@recipe, "preperation_time", "preperation_time")
 <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
 <% end %>
```

Then in the controlelr just pass the parameters directly

```
def search
 @countrysearch = Recipe.where(params).all
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i have seen another example that looks similar to yours, only difference is you are specifying [:dish_name] for example as part of the params? so rather than passing the params [:search] you are passing [:search][:dish_name]. What does passing this extra param achieve?would be interested to know as new to rails...again though thank you for your answer

Comment: I'm passing the params[:dish_name], because it enables you to pass different values in each params hash item. One for each clause. I updated the reply with another approach, you may try it, since I don't have rails here where I am!!

Comment: Sorry one more question if you dont mind, options_from_collection_for_select. This is pulling the data from my original form? this is syntax i have not seen before

Comment: select_tag documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

Comment: options_from_collection http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Comment: Basically it takes the value from a model instance

Comment: Hi Felipe, seem to be getting this error now undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass? any ideas or what areas to look at?

Comment: You may open another question for this. You have to check where you are calling the map function, and the variable that you are calling this method is null, so you hav eto check why.